# How to inject an element between each element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I want to inject something (say `0`) between each array element, like this:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

The injected element could be anything: a number, a string, a JSX element etc.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You could iterate through the array and push at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ludicrous way of doing it. I just like `reduce`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function (p, c, i, a) {
  return i < a.length - 1 ? p.concat(c, 0) : p.concat(c);
}, []);
```

If the injected element varies, just wrap the code in a function.

```
function stuffer(arr, el) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, c, i, a) {
    return i < a.length - 1 ? p.concat(c, el) : p.concat(c);
  }, []);
}

stuffer(arr, '<p>Hi</p>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The sanest way is to simply create a new array:

```
var arr    = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i], 0);
}
```

A less sane way would involve using `Array.splice` a lot.

Comment: Minor nitpick - this adds a `0` at the end of `newArr` too

Comment: Meh, yeah, I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader... ;)

Answer (score 0):

just join and split back

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
alert( arr.join(',0,').split(',') );
```

can be refactored into a method

```
function insertBetweenAllElements( arr, newElement )
{
   return arr.join(',' + newElement  + ',').split(',')
}
var updatedArr = insertBetweenAllElements( arr, '0' ) 
alert( updatedArr );
```

Adding support for all kinds of data (int, str, etc)

```
function insertBetweenAllElements( arr, newElement )
{
   arr.forEach( function( value, index, arr ){ arr.splice(index+index, 0, newElement ); } )
   return arr.slice(1,arr.length);
}
var updatedArr = insertBetweenAllElements( arr, '0' ) 
alert( updatedArr );
```

Comment: That's fine for the given example, but you have to start being concerned what the actual elements of the array are if you're dealing with strings that may contain commas etc.

Comment: That's my bad, I edited my answer to further define the injected element. Thanks for adding the solution for other data types.

Comment: @silvenon if you find this useful, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'd class this as elegant - but it works (and it's in place, no temporary arrays were harmed or used in this code)

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
function insertBetween(arr, val) {
    arr.map(function(e, i) { if (i) arr.splice(i * 2 - 1, 0, val) }); 
}
insertBetween(array, 0);
```